# What is the meaning of 'is' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading 'Black as Snow' by Nick Nolan and encountered this sentence.

> "It's never easy." *Libby laughed while clinking her cup with is.* "But it works."

What's the meaning of 'is' in this sentence?

Plural 'i'? Typo?

Comment: Looks like a typo. Does with *ice* make sense in the context? Or with *his*?

Comment: @Autoresponder ahh.. *his* is the correct word, I think.

Comment: Might be "ease" misspelled... (I'm joking). Most probably there's an *h* missing (i.e. *h*is) otherwise - to me - it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep! It's supposed to be 'his'. TYPO! Thought we got 'em all!

Comment: "You can ne'er get all the typohs... They creep in, in the darkest o' night, whilst you be asheep, and add themselves inconspicuously in the most infuriatingly of playses." - Fainswift.

Comment: @Nick Wow, thank you for answering my question! It is honorable time of my life :) And the book is really good (55% so far).

Answer (score 6):

It’s almost certainly a typo for *his*.

Comment: `his` -- I was staring at that sentence, trying to imagine what word would go there.  I bet Nick Nolan is *mad*.